# do Python's Selenium module and the selenium-webdriver node package implement frame switching differently?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, firefox

I am experimenting a little with the [Selenium](https://www.selenium.dev/) bindings for both [Python](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/) and [Javascript](https://www.npmjs.com/package/selenium-webdriver) and am seeing some differences I do not understand.

Specifically, I am using two scripts (one Python, one a `.js` run with `node`) to

- open a Firefox window at `abut:blank`
- open the [console](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Web_Console) (i.e. automate the `Ctrl+Shift+k` shortcut)
- find the iframe made available in [chrome context](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/javascript/module/selenium-webdriver/firefox_exports_Driver.html#setContext) upon opening the console
- switch to that iframe
- count all of the buttons in the resulting document

#### Python

The script is

```py
from selenium.webdriver import Firefox, DesiredCapabilities, FirefoxProfile
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

import time
import traceback

options = Options()
webdriver = Firefox(options=options)
webdriver.get("about:blank")
try:
    time.sleep(3)
    with webdriver.context(webdriver.CONTEXT_CHROME):
        time.sleep(3)

        console = webdriver.find_element(By.ID, "tabbrowser-tabs")
        console.send_keys(Keys.LEFT_CONTROL + Keys.LEFT_SHIFT + 'k')        
        time.sleep(3)        

        ifr = webdriver.find_element_by_class_name("devtools-toolbox-bottom-iframe")
        webdriver.switch_to.frame(ifr)

        elts = webdriver.find_elements_by_tag_name("button")
        print(len(elts)) 
                       
except Exception as error:
    traceback.print_exc()
```

This prints back `13` (so it found 13 buttons). If, on the other hand, I comment out the line

```
webdriver.switch_to.frame(ifr)
```

(i.e. I don't switch to the frame) then it prints out `5`.

#### Javascript

Here the script is

```js
var webdriver = require('selenium-webdriver'),
    By = webdriver.By,
    until = webdriver.until;

var firefox = require('selenium-webdriver/firefox');
var inpt = require('selenium-webdriver/lib/input');

var options = new firefox.Options();

var driver = new webdriver.Builder()
    .forBrowser('firefox')
    .setFirefoxOptions(options)
    .build();

(async function(){
    await driver.get('about:blank');
    await driver.setContext("chrome");

    var tabs = await driver.findElement(By.id('tabbrowser-tabs'));
    await tabs.sendKeys(inpt.Key.CONTROL + inpt.Key.SHIFT + 'k');    

    var el, btns;
        
    setTimeout(
    async () => {el = await driver.findElement(By.css('.devtools-toolbox-bottom-iframe')); },
    3000
    );
        
    await driver.switchTo().frame(el);

    setTimeout(
    async () => {
        btns = await driver.findElements(By.css("button"));
        await console.log(btns.length);
    },
    10000
    );    
})();
```

This (run with `node`) will print out `5` no matter what I do, regardless of whether or not I leave the frame-switching line

```
await driver.switchTo().frame(el);
```

in there.

It doesn't error out so I know it finds the frame and succeeds in whatever `switchTo` is supposed to do, but the 5 buttons it finds seem to be the same whether or not the `switchTo` is there (I've also printed out their classes and ids, etc.; the behavior is identical with or without the switch command).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the answer to my question is 'no', and I think I understand what happened: the `async/await` thing bit me, being a newbie..

In the snippet

```js
var el, btns;
        
    setTimeout(
    async () => {el = await driver.findElement(By.css('.devtools-toolbox-bottom-iframe')); },
    3000
    );
        
    await driver.switchTo().frame(el);
```

the `switchTo` happens, I think, *before* assigning to `el`, because I placed that `switchTo` outside the `setTimeout`. So when the `switchTo` happens `el` is `undefined`, which doesn't raise an error (I've checked that you can `switchTo` an `undefined` frame with no issue).

Moving that switch command into the timeout as in

```js
var el, btns;
        
    setTimeout(
        async () => {
            el = await driver.findElement(By.css('.devtools-toolbox-bottom-iframe'));
            await driver.switchTo().frame(el);
        },
        3000
    );
```

brings the Python and Javascript versions into agreement.